# Formula for moving data data from date range to individual date

Tags: indexing, match, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need help with a formula in excel 2010.

I have 2 workbooks

One has....

```
ref  No     startdate  enddate value  
A    1      3/01/12    7/02/12  56  
A    1      8/02/12    1/03/12  45  
B    2      1/01/12   15/02/12  36  
B    2      16/02/12  04/04/12  59
```

In the other workbook I have it as

```
ref  No   01/01/12  02/01/12   03/01/12...  
A    1  
B    2
```

I have to put the data form the value underneath the corresponding date in the 2nd workbook from the date ranges and the matched `ref` and `No`. I do understand that the value will go under many individual dates...that's what I want.

Does anyone know of a formula that can index match and sort this data accordingly?

Also, to copy and paste the formula so the data matches the `ref` and `No` going down the column and matches the date going across the top row?

Hope you can help

Thanks in advance

Ricky

Answer (score 1):

It is simple with a Helper column (witouth is possible but much more difficult).
Add a New A column, and concatenate Ref e No to create a key
In A2 type:

> =B2&"_"&C2

Drag the formula down along your matrix of data

Then go to the second table and crate a key accordingly.
In my test (see image) type in I2 cell:

> =J2&"_"&K2

[image]

Now we have all the piece in place. In L2 put:

> =IFERROR(IF(AND(VLOOKUP($I2,$A$1:$F$6,4,FALSE)<=L$1,VLOOKUP($I2,$A$1:$F$6,5,FALSE)>=L$1),VLOOKUP($I2,$A$1:$F$6,6,FALSE),0),0)

Then drag the formula left and down. you must of course modify the boundaries (expecially the F6 in the long formula - I have only 6 row -, according to your data).

Done.

Comment: Thanks  I'll play around with that and will let you know how it goes.